# Timer stops despite background capability is enabled

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I am using `AVAudioPlayer` to play a looping sound. My current code has this line: `audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1` , which causes indefinite loop. I use a timer to stop the looping audio after a certain period of time. This works when app is in the foreground, but not after it goes to the background.

The background capabilities of my app are:

[image]

Despite the background mode is enabled and audio is playing while the app goes to the background, the app *seems like* it is suspended right after `applicationDidEnterBackground` was called. I say so because (1) timer stops printing output at every second to the console (2) audio keeps playing indefinitely even after timer should have ended.

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15936892/3780985) that this must not be the case, app should not be suspended if an audio is playing in the background, but this seems like not the case in my app.

What am I missing here? What should I do to make the timer actually run in the background, besides playing a looping sound if it is not enough?

The code to run the audio:

```
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    do {
        let (fileName, fileExtension) = fileNameExtension(fileName: soundFileName)
        let soundURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: fileExtension)!)
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()            
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.allowAirPlay, .allowBluetooth, .allowBluetoothA2DP, .mixWithOthers])            
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Fetch error: \(error) description: \(error.userInfo)")
        }   
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Fetch error: \(error) description: \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1        
    audioPlayer.play()
```

The code to run the timer. This code runs while app is in the foreground.:

```
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] _ in
        self?.updateTimer()
    })        
    RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .common)        
    timer.tolerance = 0.2
```

updateTimer:

```
@objc func updateTimer() {        
    remainingTime -= 1              
    if remainingTime <= 0.0 {
       complete()
    }        
}
```

Comment: @matt Thank you for your response. I have assumed that because of the following reasons (1) my timer prints an output at every second in the debug console. However, after I see applicationDidEnterBackground in the console, timer stops printing any output, while app was in the background, (2) audio keeps playing indefinitely in the background even after the timer should have ended. I must be missing something here but I can't see it...

Comment: Yes @matt, I am testing on a device.

Comment: @matt Thanks for the link. I was reading it. Looking at your code in AppDelegate, my first guess is that I failed the keep audio session properly active. I've added some hopefully relevant code. Just let me know if you want me to share anything else.

Comment: Here is a tiny downloadable example. https://github.com/mattneub/timerRunsInBackground Download it. Build it. Run it. Put it into the background. Watch the Console in Xcode. The sound loops and the timer runs ("tick tock" in the Console). One counterexample is sufficient to disprove the theorem, as my father used to say.

Comment: @matt How could I not see it... Yes! The timer is being invalidated while app goes to the background... ‍♂️ Please write an answer and let me accept it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has some false premises:

- `applicationDidEnterBackground` does not mean your app will be suspended. It *usually* does, but if you have the audio background mode capability and the `playback` audio category, and you are playing sound when you go into the background, you are not suspended; instead, you run in the background.
- A timer that is started before you go into the background *does* work in the background under those circumstances.

So if you're hearing sound in the background from your app but your timer is *not* firing, that must be due to something else you're doing. Perhaps you've configured things so that the timer is invalidated when you go into the background?